# Using javascript to update html css code on validation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form in my html and below is one of its components or fields.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock"></i></span>
        <div id="form_field" class="fg-line">
            <input name="pas" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to add `has-error` to class `fg-line` if the input field is blank.

I tried that using the code below apparently it only adds to the first `form-field` it encounters which its understandable but what I don't know is how to get it to only apply `has-error` to the  input field which is empty.

```
function validateForm() {
    var isValid = true;
    $('.form-control').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            isValid = false;

            $("#form_field").removeClass("fg-line").addClass("fg-line has-error");
        }
    });
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: You're using and id inside the validation function, so it will only work for that "id". Use generic class instead.

Comment: Check this link:-https://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your structure, does the input you're testing always come as a direct child as the div you're looking to modify? You can grab the current element in the loop's parent by doing `$(this).parent()` as seen here:

```
function validateForm() {
    var isValid = true;
    $('.form-control').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            isValid = false;

            //Add has-error class to the parent div
            $(this).parent().addClass("has-error");
        }
    });
    return isValid;
}
```

Otherwise, you can use `.closest()` which will traverse upwards along the DOM tree and find the first matching occurrence of the specified selector.

```
function validateForm() {
    var isValid = true;
    $('.form-control').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            isValid = false;

            //Add has-error class to the closest occurrence of class fg-line
            $(this).closest('.fg-line').addClass("has-error");
        }
    });
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked. I had being trying this all day long `.parentNode`

Comment: Not a problem! If you've found this answer completely satisfies your question, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). :)

Comment: Upvotes for questions are reserved to make them more commonly found, or to praise a thought-provoking or shared interest question. Being that yours is very specific and an extremely common issue, I don't personally think there is merit in upvoting. Apologies.